# How to use local plugins for jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

My jekyll site is hosted on a server, where I just upload the `_site` folder.

Everything works great.

However, I want to add local plugins. When I add files to my *new* `_plugins` folder, they are ignored and I get the `Liquid syntax error (line 7): Unknown tag ...` error for my newly declared tags.

Based on what I read here and on the jekyll.rb site, the problem may be that I have a `github-pages` gem in my Gemfile.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
group :jekyll_plugins do
    gem 'github-pages'
    gem 'jekyll'
    gem 'jekyll-paginate'
    gem 'jekyll-scholar'
    gem 'jemoji'
end
```

However, if I delete the `gem 'github-pages'` line, I end up with this error:

```
 Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have pygments or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- pygments' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/!
```

If I install pygments, I still get the same error, but the installation appears successful

```
$ gem install pygments.rb          [8:05:33]
Fetching: pygments.rb-1.2.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed pygments.rb-1.2.1
Parsing documentation for pygments.rb-1.2.1
Installing ri documentation for pygments.rb-1.2.1
Done installing documentation for pygments.rb after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

What can I do so that my local plugins are usable? (I really just want to be able to embed local video, so I added a plugin for that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because you haven't added `pygments.rb` to your `Gemfile`
Simply add it to the `Gemfile` and this error should go away.

```ruby
# Gemfile

gem 'jekyll'
gem 'pygments.rb'

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem 'jekyll-paginate'
  gem 'jekyll-scholar'
  gem 'jemoji'
end
```

Comment: This is so helpful. I had put the gem 'pygments.rb' under the plugins and just ended up with more errors.